# MIDI MediaDataSource not working with MediaPlayer

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, midi

I'm trying to get the android.media.MediaPlayer to play MIDI without writing it to a file first.

I have code that builds up a MIDI file's content then writes it to a stream / file / byte array / etc. I tried implementing an android.media.MediaDataSource that reads from a byte array but after setting it as the datasource I get an IOException when I call MediaPlayer.prepare ("Prepare failed.: status=0x1"). If I write the same byte array to a file and use that as the data source everything works fine.

I tried looking through the android source for something that might be different when using a file, and for other attributes that might need to be set on the MediaPlayer, but nothing jumped out at me.

Hoping someone can spot what I'm doing wrong.

```
package com.example.cantmakemidiwork;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.media.MediaDataSource;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        byte[] midiBytes = new byte[]{

                'M', 'T', 'h', 'd',         // Chunk type HEADER ({77, 84, 104, 100})
                0, 0, 0, 6,                 // Chunk data length
                0, 0,                       // File format 0
                0, 1,                       // Number of tracks 1
                0x01, (byte) 0xE0,          // Division 480 (0x01E0, { 1, -32 })

                // TRACK DATA
                'M', 'T', 'r', 'k',         // Chunk type TRACK ({77, 84, 114, 107})
                0, 0, 0, 12,                // Chunk data length

                // Events
                0,                          // Zero delta for note on start
                (byte)(0x90 | 0x00),        // Note On status / channel 0
                52,                         // Note number 52 (E3)
                80,                         // Velocity 80 (range 0-127)

                (byte) 0x8F, 0x0,           // 1920 tick delta (480 x 4) Variable Length Quantity
                                            // Skip byte for running status
                52,                         // Note number 52 (E3)
                0,                          // Velocity 0 (effective note off)

                0,                          // Zero delta (since note off)
                (byte) 0xFF, 0x2F, 0x0      // End track event
        };

        boolean useFile = true;

        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

        if (useFile) {

            String filePath = getCacheDir().getPath() + "/tmpMidi.mid";

            File inputFile = new File(filePath);
            try {
                FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(inputFile);
                outputStream.write(midiBytes);
                outputStream.flush();
                outputStream.close();

                mediaPlayer.setDataSource(filePath);

            } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            } catch (IOException ex) { }

        } else {

            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(new MidiDataSource(midiBytes));
        }

        try {
            // Fails if we used the MidiDataSource, works if we used the MIDI file.
            mediaPlayer.prepare();

        } catch (IOException ex) {

            int x = 7; // Just a line to put a breakpoint on.

        }
        mediaPlayer.start();

        try { mediaPlayer.wait(5000); } catch (java.lang.InterruptedException ex) { }
    }
}

class MidiDataSource extends MediaDataSource {

    private byte[] _data;

    public MidiDataSource(byte[] data) { _data = data; }

    @Override
    public long getSize() throws java.io.IOException {
        return _data.length;
    }

    @Override
    public int readAt(long position, byte[] buffer, int offset, int size) throws java.io.IOException {

        int length = _data.length;

        if (position >= length) { return -1; }

        if (size == 0) { return 0; }

        if (position + size > length) {

            size = (int) (length - position);
        }

        System.arraycopy(_data, (int)position, buffer, offset, size);

        return size;
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws IOException {}

}
```

UPDATE:

I tried reading an MP3 file into a byte array and using that for the MediaDataSource data and it worked.

Comment: Wow... Nobody answered. I have exactly the same problem with midi and custom MediaDataSource. Do not want to write it to filesystem. So... On Android API 29..24 my byte array (wrapped with MediaDataSource) works fine. On Marshmallow API 23 it fails on prepare call with "status=0x1".

Comment: @vitvlkv I think my UPDATE might have unintentionally suggested that I solved the problem. When I came back to read it I saw that and was like "when tf did I make this work?!" lol. Good to know it works on later versions. I had actually found the issue in the MediaPlayer source but never went through with submitting a patch.